# How to display HTML markup from telegram telego Go bot?

Tags: go, telebot

I'd like to push a formatted message to to clients from my bot in much the same way as the Durger King app does. In response to any input to the bot a message showing for formatted 'Let's get started' is displayed along with a picture. Underneath there is `order food` WebApp button which opens the PWA.

Is this simply and image or is it formatted HTML, which would possibly be easier to manage.

How can one send either a an image or formatted HTML using the telego Go bot.

[image]

Comment: The response in the image above seems to be formatted text, as I can copy and paste while preserving some of the format.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what is probably the wrong way of achieving this:

```
var (helloMsg    = &tele.Message{Text: "<b>Let's get started!</b>"})

func main() {   
pref := tele.Settings{
    Token:  os.Getenv("TOKEN"),
    Poller: &tele.LongPoller{Timeout: 5 * time.Second},
}

b, err := tele.NewBot(pref)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return
}

    b.Handle("/start", func(c tele.Context) error {
    log.Println("Detected Start")
    b.Send(c.Message().Sender, helloMsg.Text, &tele.SendOptions{
        ParseMode: "HTML",
    }, webapp)
    return nil
})}
}
```

I haven't tried to see if it is possible to use the context instead of the bot itself, and returning `nil` probably isn't a great idea. But essentially you this is setting the ParseMode to HTML and somehow the emoji can be pasted in...

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version using the context:

```
b.Handle("/start", func(c tele.Context) error {
    log.Println("Detected Start")
    b.Send(c.Message().Sender, helloMsg.Text, &tele.SendOptions{
        ParseMode: "HTML",
    }, webapp)
    return nil
})
```